# Strange behaviour when pasting strings consisting of phone number

Tags: r, stringr

I have extracted data (`df`) from a WhatsApp chat and built a variable called `name`. Now, in some instances, I don't have names, but phone numbers.

So, in the next step, I try to assign every number a name. Now, R shows a strange behaviour (sorry, I know no other name for this):

When I type `which(df$name=="‪+49 176 12345678‬")` in the console, R somehow changes this to `which(df$name=="*+49 176 12345678,")` (and then, of course, can't find any instances of this number). At the same time, there seems to be an "unseen space": when my cursor is directly right of the "8" and I press backspace, the "7" gets deleted.

In case this helps: when viewing the variable (`View(df$name)`), R does not show me the numbers like `+49 176 12345678‬`, but `<U+202A>+49 176 12345678‬<U+202C>`. However, these unicode control characters do not appear when using (e.g.) ``table(df$name)`.

Comment: What's the connection with `stringr`?

Comment: Also, a way for us to replicate this behaviour would be nice.

Comment: When I copy "‪+49 176 12345678‬" from your question I can reproduce your issue, but when I type in the phone number on a new line, I can't reproduce it.  One possible solution is to use substr and slice from 2 to n-1.

Comment: Try stripping non-ASCII characters with the approach suggested here: https://gist.github.com/nassimhaddad/4643587. n.m., didn't work

Comment: Since we can't replicate your problem, can you try to `gsub("[^0-9 ]","",x)` where x is df$name? The idea is to try to remove any non numeric or space from the string.

Comment: @AkselA: I'm really sorry I can't offer you a way to reproduce it, but you will understand that I can not put this chat online. The connection with `stringr` is admittedly weak, I chose the label since it is a stringr-related problem.

Comment: @Dave2e: I tried your suggestion by assigning `substr(df$name[9], 2, nchar(dibbe$Name[9])-1)`, which gives a number, to an object `number`, and then searching via `number <- substr(dibbe$Name[9], 2, nchar(dibbe$Name[9])-1)` - no results.

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre: Thank you, that did the trick! Can I somehow promote your comment to a solution?

Comment: Just made it an answer. I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos: your answer works, as well. I prefer the answer by 
JosephClarkMcIntyre because it leaves all other signs (e.g. the ´+´) as they are, and thus it seems more generalisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try stripping non-ASCII characters with the approach suggested here: gist.github.com/nassimhaddad/4643587. It looks like the issue you're encountering is, as you identified, there are some hidden characters in your strings. They're creating all sorts of weird behavior. Running `df$text <- gsub("[^\x20-\x7E]", "", df$text)` will remove non-ASCII characters from the string, and you'll be left with only the numbers and characters that you see in the display.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the cause of the problem might be - just so I additionally understand what you just solved?

Comment: I think it was the hidden characters. Your explanation was exactly right, and the solution just gets rid of those hidden characters.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a url to a resource.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm new to the site and don't know the etiquette. Can I make it into an answer by elaborating? Or should I just remove it?

Comment: Elaborate, maybe explain hidden characters. The main point is that it should still be a useful post even if that github gist were to disappear.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I appreciate it.